# how to pass a date selected in jQuery calendar to php?

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

I am trying to make a simple calendar in jQuery. I want the user to select some date and then I have to do some stuff with that on server - php side. I would like to pass the selected date in some format like "dd/mm/yyyy" from JS to php. Could you please help me to find some way to do that?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/ion.calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="datum"></div>
    <div id="result">...</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/ion.calendar.js"></script> 

    <script>

    $(function(){
        $("#datum").ionCalendar({
            lang: "sk",
            years: "2000-2050",
            sundayFirst: false,
            onClick: function(date){
                $("#result").html(date);    
                                });
                });


    </script>


    <?php

    //there i want to handle the date I selected

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: You need to search for jquery PHP AJAX and rephrase the question to not try to access PHP on the client. Make two questions (if you need the second after finding the hundreds or thousands of jquery PHP AJAX examples)

Comment: Only ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Ion Calendar has a `format` configuration.

To pass the date to PHP, you either have to submit a form, or make an ajax request.

```
$("#datum").ionCalendar({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    lang: "sk",
    years: "2000-2050",
    sundayFirst: false,
    onClick: function(date) {
        // Form field
        $("#input").val(date);

        // Ajax request
        $.post('localhost/send/date', date);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point I worked with JQuery calendar, and now I can only imagine two ways of doing that.

1. Put the selected date of the JQuery calendar into the value of an 'input' field in the form that you are going to submit it. I usually use hidden inputs for that purpose but you can let the input be visible if you want. After that, during the submiting process, parse the 'data' that comes from the input with the date chosen by the user.
2. Using Ajax to some endpoint.

I'm pretty certain that the JQuery calendar has an option to customize the data format of its choosen value, but in case that it doesn't have an option,  I suggest the idea of parsing the input 'data'. Then if you want to change the chosen value in real time, bind / listen any change in the input with the onChange() method of Jquery.